# Building SQL request for JSON API

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a website built on wordpress and would like to create a SQL query for displaying users points by their username.

Points in the table linked to users IDs and not to usernames. My SQL query is:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE user_login='{username}'

SELECT points 
FROM wp_cp 
WHERE uid=ID
```

Which is wrong. Separately they work fine but how can I make only one SQL query?

The logic should be by typing username - SQL gets its ID from **wp_users** and automatically points number from **wp_cp** by matching users ID.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you missed the JOIN class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you hav a litle hint,

```
SELECT points 
    FROM wp_cp join wp_users 
    on wp_cp.uid=wp_users.ID 
    where wp_users.user_login ='username'
```

DISCLAIMER: I DIDNT TEST IT, this is just a hint!

Comment: Thank you Melon. It is very close but still not working. ;-( Maybe because wp_cp has got column uid and wp_users has got column ID

Comment: try it now, it just missed the tablenames on colums. you can finish it from there.